# Calculating ionic strength and pH of a buffer solution

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, ph

Im trying to calculate ion strength and pH of solution.

Components of the solution:
47 ul of 1000 pmol DNA in Elution Buffer (10 mM Tris-HCl pH 8.5) was bound to 3 ul of 10 µM YoYo1 (flourescent dye) in DMSO and was mixed with 50 ul of Tris-EDTA buffer (100 mM Tris-HCl, 0.01 M EDTA pH 8.0).

About calculation of ion strength, Im confused what Ions are in the solution too.
Tris-HCl => Tris-H + Cl- ?
EDTA => Mg2+ + Ca2+??
DMSO => ??

Furthermore, how can I calculate it?

I think the pH range is about 8.0~8.5, because of two buffers.
Is there any method for calculating more exact pH value?

Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: Why do you suppose TrisHCl EDTA buffer contains Ca/Mg ?